# Get the ProcessList like from cmd+tab

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I want to get the applications from the cmd+tab menu in OS X. The best way I got now is to associate this with a AppleScript call with the following:

```
NSDictionary *errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *returnValue;
NSString *appleScriptText = @"tell application \"System Events\" to get name of (processes where background only is false)";
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:appleScriptText];
```

Then loop through the stuff coming back from it and to match it to the `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]` but this seems a little bit too weird to get this task done.

So my question here: is there a way that is not so quirky like this one?

I am really tense for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're already familiar with `-[NSWorkspace runningApplications]`, why don't you just iterate over those and check which ones meet your criteria?  The `background only` property corresponds to `NSRunningApplication`'s `activationPolicy` property being something other than `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`.

So, something like (not tested):

```
NSArray* apps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
NSIndexSet* indexes = [apps indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [obj activationPolicy] == NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular;
}];
NSArray* names = [[apps objectsAtIndexes:indexes] valueForKey:@"localizedName"];
```

Comment: 'Doh didn't payed attention to that kind of property… but i didn't find anything else! This is the solution! Thanks a lot!